# How to treat underscore as white space extracting document number

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, match, matching

Invoice words are sometimes delimited by underscore character (_) in addition or instead of white space:

```
...
Some nr_11687767_ other 101308591
Invoice Nr.
M230714_some text
Kirjeldus
...
```

Sometimes it is terminated by newline

```
...
This nr_11687767_KMKR_EE101308591
Invoice Nr.
M230714
01.05.2023
Item
...
```

or by other white space delimiter :

```
...
Some  nr_11687767_ Text
Invoice Nr M230714   Date 01.05.2023
Desc
...
```

Tried to extract number using RegEx

```
  Regex.Match(tekst, @"(?si).*_?Invoice[\s_]?NR[\s_:\.]?(?<arvenumber>.*?)[\s_]");
```

Success is true but arvenumber group is empty.

How to get only number M230714  in arvenumber group ?

Using C# ASP.NET 7

Comment: `[\s_]` - either whitespace or `_`

Comment: You could match word characters without an underscore like `^Reg nr.*\r?\nInvoice(?: Nr\.)?\s*(?<arvenumber>(?<number>[^\W_]+)(?:_|\s+)[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/oHP6up/1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I tried your suggestion but arvenumber group is empty. I updadet question. How to get invoice number?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Invoice number may be terminated by something otder than 99.99.9999 pattern. I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus You could get that number only like this `^Reg nr_.*\r?\nInvoice(?: Nr\.?)?\s*(?<number>[^\W_]+)(?![^\s_])` https://regex101.com/r/thxzAL/1 or https://regex101.com/r/kEYS2q/1

Comment: `(?si)Invoice\s+Nr\.?[\s_]+(?<arvenumber>[\p{L}0-9]+)`

Comment: You updated the question again, so perhaps `^Invoice Nr\.?\s*(?<arvenumber>[^\W_]+)[\s_]` https://regex101.com/r/6seOz1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a pattern like this

```
(?i)Invoice\s+Nr\.?[\s_]+(?<arvenumber>[\p{L}0-9]+)
```

where

```
(?i)                        - Ignore case when matching
Invoice                     - "Invoice"
\s+                         - One or more whitespaces
Nr\.?                       - "Nr" with optional .  
[\s_]+                      - One or more namespaces or _
(?<arvenumber>[\p{L}0-9]+)  - arvenumber which contains of letters and / or digits
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/Dyh6Lz/1)

Comment: I tried this with modified pattern but arvenumber group is empty. I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus: I see; let's try a pattern, not an idea

Answer (score 1):

You can omit using `(?s)` as that will make the dot match a newline as well, which may [cause matching too much](https://regex101.com/r/TCOQCW/1).

Then take the dot out of the character class and only make that optional like `\.?[\s_:.]` followed by 1 character out of the character class.

```
(?i).*Invoice[\s_]?NR\.?[\s_:.](?<arvenumber>.*?)[\s_]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ILFCmn/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/gzzkB0)

Or a bit more specific:

```
(?i)^Invoice[\p{Zs}\t]+Nr\.?\s*(?<arvenumber>[^\W_]+)[\s_]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for case insensitive
- `^` Start of string
- `Invoice[\p{Zs}\t]+Nr\.?` Match `Invoice` followed by 1+ spaces without newlines, and then `Nr` with optional `.`
- `\s*` match optional whitespce chars which can also match newlines
- `(?<arvenumber>[^\W_]+)` Group *arvenumber* matching 1+ word chars without `_`
- `[\s_]` Match either a whitespace char or `_` if that is mandatory

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYoGFe/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/r3Bx5c)